# tvOS: can I update the UI of the highlighted list item?

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I am discovering tvOS and I tried this simple UI:

```
struct TeamListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(teams.sorted(by: { $0.points > $1.points })) { team in
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(team.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(team.points)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Team: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let points: Int
    let creationYear: Int
    
    var id: String {
        return name
    }
}

let teams: [Team] = [
    Team(name: "Inter Milan", points: 39, creationYear: 1898),
    Team(name: "Milan AC", points: 33, creationYear: 1902),
    Team(name: "Juventus", points: 31, creationYear: 1900),
    Team(name: "SSC Napoli", points: 48, creationYear: 1910),
    Team(name: "Hellas Vérone", points: 10, creationYear: 1922),
    Team(name: "Cagliari", points: 21, creationYear: 19333)
]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to update the UI of the white highlighting background, i.e. setting a radius to the corners?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Removing the padding that you have on your `VStack` should remove the clipping you have with the Buttons, but tvOS Buttons use a particular style and hover effect, and overriding that style is a little difficult. Apple advises to use the `CardButtonStyle` for any custom modifications, but you are able to find some of what you're wanting to do around here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178436/8281364

You can also find a some knowledge that Asperi shared about focus states with the buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172333/8281364